# why jquery function not working in modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog, shopping-cart

I have jquery code for add to Cart in E-commerce app.
here problem is when i click on add to cart on index page it works fine.item successfully moves to cart.

[image]
But when I press **Quick View** a Modal will open with product detail.
On modal i have Same this button And on clicking that button item isn't moving to cart.

Following is my Code for open modal.

```
 <a class="add_bag" data-id="<?=$row_category[0];?>" data-name="<?=$row_category[3];?>" data-summary="<?=$row_category[3];?>" data-price="<?=$row_category[6];?>" data-quantity="1" data-image="<?=$row_category[13];?>" ><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to bag</a>
```

And here is my jquery code

```
$(function () {

    var goToCartIcon = function($addTocartBtn){
      var $cartIcon = $(".shopping_bag_btn");
      var $image = $('<img width="30px" height="30px" src="' + $addTocartBtn.data("image") + '"/>').css({"position": "absolute", "z-index": "999"});
      $addTocartBtn.prepend($image);
      var position = $cartIcon.position();
      $image.animate({
        top: 0,
        right: 0
      }, 500 , "linear", function() {
        $image.remove();
      });
    }

    $('.add_bag').myCart({
      classCartIcon: 'shopping_bag_btn',
      classCartBadge: 'my-cart-badge',
      classProductQuantity: 'my-product-quantity',
      classProductRemove: 'my-product-remove',
      classCheckoutCart: 'my-cart-checkout',
      affixCartIcon: true,
      showCheckoutModal: true,
      clickOnAddToCart: function($addTocart){
        goToCartIcon($addTocart);
      },
      clickOnCartIcon: function($cartIcon, products, totalPrice, totalQuantity) {
        console.log("cart icon clicked", $cartIcon, products, totalPrice, totalQuantity);
      },
      checkoutCart: function(products, totalPrice, totalQuantity) {
        console.log("checking out", products, totalPrice, totalQuantity);
      },
      getDiscountPrice: function(products, totalPrice, totalQuantity) {
        console.log("calculating discount", products, totalPrice, totalQuantity);
        return totalPrice;
      }

    });


  });
```

No Console error will found.
i am really getting confused.i dont know what i have to do.
So please suggest any debug method.
i also put alert in my add to cart jquery. but alert also not showing.means jquery is not working in modal.

please help.thanks.

Comment: did you have the script you mention on index page

Comment: yes i have the script. i  <?php include('include/shopping-cart.php');?> in last.

Comment: so your product does not go in cart on index page ?

Comment: yes.its working in index page. but in index page on click quick view i opened modal. on that modal i put add to cart button . so on click item should have to move to cart but it doesen't. It means given jquery Is not works.

Comment: can you put alert in your add to cart jquery function and make sure its there when you click on add to cart

Comment: yes i tried to put alert but its not work in modal.
but its wok on index page(Out of modal).

Comment: you must be calling your add to cart function in jquery on button click check if your modals button has same selector